# SQL problems on order

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I list the data with id x first and then followed by numerical order?
For instance, I have data like this:

```
0,
1,
1,
0,
1,
2,
56,
4
```

and I want the following result:

```
1,
1,
1,
0,
0,
2,
4,
56
```

In addition, I want the order for items with id 1 to be a column x, while the order for items with id not 1 to be a column y.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: See FIELD(). That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditionals in the `order by` clause.  Here is a simple way in MySQL:

```
order by (id = 1) desc, id;
```

The expression `id = 1` evaluates to 1 when the id takes on the specified value.  It evaluates to 0 otherwise.

The order by is saying to order by this expression first, and then by the id.

EDIT:

If you want to order everything else by another column and the columns are of the same type:

```
order by (id = 1) desc,
         (case when id = 1 then x else y end)
```

Otherwise, you can split it:

```
order by (id = 1) desc,
         (case when id = 1 then x end),
         (case when id = 1 then NULL else y end)
```

Comment: How about if I want the items with id 1 to be ordered by x while the order for items with id not 1 is y?

Comment: @SuperHandsomeGelBoy What does `x` and `y` mean here?

Comment: Names of columns, denoted by x and y

Comment: @SuperHandsomeGelBoy Then you should've told that in your question. Anyway, you can use `ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN x ELSE y END`